# python idle monitor of all mouse activity including wheel movement then run command after mouse move

Tags: python-3.x

I hope some one can help me as I don’t really know python at all and appreciate some help.

I am wanting to make a python script that runs all the time on my Linux machine that monitors all mouse activity including mouse wheel movement then after a minute of inactivity wait for mouse movement before running other external script once every given time like two minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use module named Pynput it call monitor and control you keyboard and mouse.
module link- https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput
To learn more about how to use docs pdf link - https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pynput/latest/pynput.pdf

For installation go to modules directory open command windows there and follow this command.
python setup.py install